# Update YouTrack state on issue from checkin comment in SVN

Tags: teamcity, youtrack

I've been trying to set issues to status "fixed" from my SVN commits, but it keeps on failing. This is what I've been trying as SVN comment:

> `#TCSE-20 fixed`

and

> `TCSE-20 fixed`

Where `TCSE-20` of course is my issue id. I then run my build in TeamCity, which is linked to the YouTrack project.

The comment gets recognized in YouTrack as it's added to the Comments tab. But the state remains as `Submitted`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-52002

Comment: I read somewhere that it could be related to users having unmatching names in TeamCity and YouTrack. Will look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was what I was hinting in my comment. I am the administrator of our YouTrack server, and I used my email address for the "root" account, as well as having my own user, based on my username, with the same email address. When I changed the "root" accounts email address to one of my colleagues, the commands executed correctly.

Now I would like to know how to solve this better, like disabling "root" from the user lookup function, but that will be another issue. :-)

Comment: Nikas, the purpose of this stuff with matching a TeamCity user to a YouTrack user is that in YouTrack the command gets applied on behalf of the user who actually created a VCS commit. This, among other things, implies applying considering permissions. Therefore, when using TeamCity - YouTrack integration, the users are encouraged to have identical emails in both systems.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the follow-up. We are using identical emails in all systems, but as I said above - I also am the adminstrator/root. Do you have any good ideas about this setup?

Comment: Ok, I assume then, that in the case you're describing, TeamCity failed to match VCS user to it's user. You can easily check if this assumption is correct: in TeamCity open the change and make sure it displays correct TC user name (there should be both TC name and VCS name mentioned).

Comment: No, everything is fine in TC, displaying my login name. It is YT that does the matching on my email address which becomes wrong (multiple accounts with the same address)